# C++ Bitwise adjacency matrix implementation

Tags: c++, matrix, bitwise

I have tried to implement a bitwise adjacency matrix to represent a graph with a fixed number of vertices.

- Instead of wastefully representing each connection with an integer, 64 connections are packed into a single `uint64_t`, to improve memory and hopefully performance (via improved cache locality).
- Instead of `vector<vector<uint64_t>>`, using a contiguous `vector<uint64_t>`, once again to improve cache locality.
- A user interface similar to that of an `vector<unordered_set<int>>` adjacency list:

  - `adjmat[i]` to access a row
  - `adjmat[i].contains(j)` to check edge existence between `i` and `j`.
  - `for(int neighbor : adjmat[i])` neighbor iteration.

My main motivation is just to create a really fast, efficient representation for dense graphs. However, I am quite inexperienced, and since performance optimization is quite technical, I'd really like some feedback since I might be out of my depth.

Currently some concerns I have with my code include:

- Is this actually a valid way to improve performance of an adjacency matrix? I am using memory much more efficiently, but at the expense of more arithmetic and bit-shifting operations - does that erode any potential gains?
- I want to add familiar layers of abstraction (e.g. iterators) to replicate some functionality of `vector<unordered_set<int>>`. However, since I am already operating at such a low-level, I'm worried that the overhead of an iterator offsets all potential gains - if so, how can I create that abstraction without sacrificing performance?
- Also, I can't figure out why I can't `constexpr` my constructor, and if I can't, does that make all the other `constexpr` methods useless?

Of course, any other comments or thoughts are appreciated too. Thanks!

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/Ysv73v5nq)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class BitAdjmat {
public:

    // Abstraction for a "Row" of the BitAdjmat
    class Row {
    public:
        /**
        * This row iterator should only iterate through existing edges, e.g. "1" entries.
        * I've settled for only using a read-only iterator (i.e. const_iterator), since
        * there is no way to hold a reference to a single bit.
        */
        class const_iterator {
        public:

            constexpr const_iterator(std::size_t index,
                std::vector<uint64_t>::const_iterator start,
                std::size_t end_index)
                : index{index}, start{start}, end_index{end_index}
            {
                if (!exists()) {
                    seek_next();
                }
            }

            /**
            * Warning: This is special constructor that is optimized for constructing
            * the end() iterator, and shouldn't be used for anything else.
            */
            constexpr const_iterator(std::size_t end_index,
                std::vector<uint64_t>::const_iterator start) noexcept
                : index{end_index}, start{start}, end_index{end_index} {}

            constexpr const_iterator &operator++() noexcept {
                seek_next();
                return *this;
            }

            constexpr std::size_t operator*() const noexcept { return index; }
            
            constexpr bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const noexcept { 
                return index == other.index && start == other.start; 
            }
            constexpr bool operator!=(const const_iterator &other) const noexcept { return !(*this == other); }

        private:

            // Check if current neighbor pointed to by *(start+index/N) exists, i.e., if the bit returned is 1.
            constexpr bool exists() const noexcept { return ((*(start + index / N)) >> (index % N)) & 1ULL; }

            constexpr void seek_next() noexcept {
                while (index != end_index) {
                    ++index;
                    if (exists())
                    return;
                }
            }

        private:
            std::size_t index; // logical vertex index (not vector<uint64_t> index)
            const std::vector<uint64_t>::const_iterator start;
            const std::size_t end_index;
        };

    public:

        constexpr Row(const BitAdjmat &parent, std::size_t row_index) noexcept
        : start{parent.matrix.begin() + parent.num_uint64_per_row * row_index}, 
          num_vertices{parent.num_vertices} {}
        
        constexpr bool contains(std::size_t nb_index) const noexcept { 
            return ((*(start + nb_index / N)) >> (nb_index % N)) & 1ULL; 
        }

        constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(0, start, num_vertices); }
        constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(num_vertices, start); }

    private:
        const std::vector<uint64_t>::const_iterator start;
        const std::size_t num_vertices;
    };

public:
  
    BitAdjmat(std::size_t num_vertices)
        : num_vertices{num_vertices}, 
          num_uint64_per_row{num_vertices / N + (num_vertices % N != 0)}, 
          matrix{std::vector<uint64_t>(num_vertices * num_uint64_per_row, 0)} {}

    constexpr Row operator[](std::size_t row_index) noexcept { return Row(*this, row_index); }
    constexpr const Row operator[](std::size_t row_index) const noexcept { return Row(*this, row_index); }

    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return num_vertices; }

    // Direct access to adjmat entry, where 'i' and 'j' are logical vertex indices.
    constexpr bool get(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const noexcept { 
        return (matrix[flat_index(i, j / N)] >> (j % N)) & 1ULL; 
    }

    // Direct setting of adjmat entries, where 'i' and 'j' are logical vertex indices.
    constexpr void set(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, bool val) noexcept {
        std::size_t q = j / N;
        std::size_t r = j % N;
        matrix[flat_index(i, q)] = (matrix[flat_index(i, q)] & ~(1ULL << r)) | (static_cast<uint64_t>(val) << r);
    }


private:
    const std::size_t num_vertices;
    const std::size_t num_uint64_per_row;
    std::vector<uint64_t> matrix; // Flat container representating a 2D vector<vector<uint64_t>>.

    constexpr static std::size_t N = 64;

private:
    constexpr std::size_t flat_index(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const { return i * num_uint64_per_row + j; }


};
```

Comment: You spelt `std::size_t` correctly, but not `std::uint64_t`.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I've taken exactly the same approach earlier to representing graphs with at most 64 vertices. Are you looking to solve a particular problem with this representation? I've implemented various algorithms on top of them too, including greedy coloring, maximal clique enumeration, path finding etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this actually a valid way to improve performance of an adjacency matrix?

Yes, I have used this technique in several software projects to great effect. But it only *really* works well if you actually *use* the fact that you've bit-packed your booleans, I mean beyond just saving space. By the way you cannot really use the "packedness" if you use a `vector<bool>`, so I'll make the opposite recommendation of Toby Speight: keep the `vector<uint64_t>`. But use it.

### How to use a bit-packed format

The key to actually making use of bit-packed data, is doing as much as possible with whole `uint64_t`s, and as little as possible bit-by-bit.

So don't do this, this wastes the potential that you created by packing your bits:

> ```
> constexpr void seek_next() noexcept {
>     while (index != end_index) {
>         ++index;
>         if (exists())
>         return;
>     }
> }
> ```

Instead, change your iterator state to a pair of "index of the current `uint64_t`" and "copy of current `uint64_t` but with the bits that have already been iterated over reset". Then you can do:

- While the current `uint64_t` (with the bits that have already been iterated over reset) is zero, skip ahead to the next `uint64_t`.
- If it's not zero, calculate where the next set bit is with `std::countr_zero`. Remember to reset that bit in the iterator state.

That way there is much less "searching", the only actual searching that happens is on the level of `uint64_t`s, not individual bits. Large blocks of zeroes are efficiently skipped. High-entropy blocks of 50% zeroes and 50% ones do not suffer from branch misprediction, since there is no branch per individual bit.

Here's a reference: [Daniel Lemire's blog: Iterating over set bits quickly](https://lemire.me/blog/2018/02/21/iterating-over-set-bits-quickly/). The iteration is "out in the open" there, but you can put that into an iterator. And you can use the standard `std::countr_zero` these days.

There are other operations that you can implement efficiently using similar principles, such as counting neighbours (`std::popcount`) or computing the complement graph. You can use bulk operations that treat each row as a bit set as the building blocks for graph search algorithms and such.

Comment: This is a good point. Although I would then say: create a `class bitvector` that stores the bits and provides iterators that return indices of only the bits that are 1. Add something equivalent to a `std::span` for it so you can iterate over subsets of a `bitvector`. Then you can use that class inside `BitAdjMat`. This gives you a reusable bit vector and a greatly simplified `BitAdjMat`.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty clever! And much better than my version of checking every single bit. I tried it out in my code and it definitely is faster. Although I couldn't figure out how to do it without 4 member variables. Minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/osdxMn8Ec . I needed cumulative_ to keep track of how many uint64s we pass by, and end_ so that seek_next knows when to stop.

Answer (score 3):

Most of this code seems to be a reimplementation of `std::vector<bool>`.  I think that implementing in terms of that class will result in simpler code (it may also be more efficient, and will work on platforms that don't provide `std::uint64_t`).

Comment: Thanks for bringing vector<bool> to my attention. I tried a version with vector<bool> instead of manual bit operations and the logic was much simpler since I could just use its iterators, with comparable performance.

Answer (score 3):

This looks nice, but I agree with Toby Speight that you should leverage [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) instead, which would get rid of a lot of code. I just want to add:

## About your concerns

> - Is this actually a valid way to improve performance of an adjacency matrix? I am using memory much more efficiently, but at the expense of more arithmetic and bit-shifting operations - does that erode any potential gains?

Accessing memory, especially if it's not already in the L1 cache, is quite slow compared to simple arithmetic and bit-shifting operations. Your solution also has to do less pointer indirection. So I am pretty sure your solution is more performant compared to having a set of nested containers containing integer indices. However, you should not take my word for it, you should actually measure it: create a realistic benchmark for what you want to do with this (for example, do you want to do a minimum spanning tree or breadth-first search on the matrix), then run it with two different implementations of the adjacency matrix, and measure the time and memory it takes.

> - I want to add familiar layers of abstraction (e.g. iterators) to replicate some functionality of `vector<unordered_set<int>>`. However, since I am already operating at such a low-level, I'm worried that the overhead of an iterator offsets all potential gains - if so, how can I create that abstraction without sacrificing performance?

The iterators don't add overhead. You need some way to iterate over the neighbors, regardless of whether you implement the iterators yourself, or whether `std::unordered_set<int>` would provide iterators for you. Typically, iterators only live for the duration of a loop, they will be inlined and can be heavily optimized by the compiler.

> - Also, I can't figure out why I can't `constexpr` my constructor,

This is probably because your constructor has to construct a `std::vector`, which in turn is not `constexpr` before C++20. Since C++20 `std::vector` has gotten `constexpr` constructors, so try compiling it with the `-std=c++20` or `/std:c++20` (for MSVC) flags.

> and if I can't, does that make all the other `constexpr` methods useless?

Since C++20 everything can be made `constexpr`. Before that, it would indeed have been useless, although it never hurts to prepare for a future where `constexpr` is possible, so the more functions you can make compile with `constexpr`, the better.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I tried comparing it to an equivalent class using vector<unordered_set<int>> and it did seem significantly faster for adjacency iteration, at least for sparse/dense graphs with ~1000 vertices which was my use case.